# Terraform GCP "API has not been used in project" for the wrong project

Tags: terraform, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to create a `google_kms_key_ring` in project `b89d`. When I run `terraform apply`, I can see the `google_kms_key_ring` `project` field is set to the project I want:

```bash
 + resource "google_kms_key_ring" "main_key_ring" {
      + id       = (known after apply)
      + location = "northamerica-northeast1"
      + name     = "key-ring-test"
      + project  = "b89d"
    }
```

However when I execute this plan, I get the error "Cloud Key Management Service (KMS) API has not been used in project XXXXXXXXX before or it is disabled".

Project `XXXXXXXXX` is a completely different project. It seems that project `b89d` that I specified is being ignored. I verified via the GCP console that the KMS API **is** enabled in the project I want (`b89d`), but terraform / GCP complains it is not enabled in a different project. How can I fix this?

I can see in the terraform logs, it submits the correct url:

```
POST /v1/projects/b89d/locations/northamerica-northeast1/keyRings?alt=json&keyRingId=key-ring-test HTTP/1.1
```

I don't know why it's complaining about the API being enabled in a different project.

Comment: Seems related to https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-google/issues/10066

Comment: Post a minimal example that reproduces the problem. Fragments do not help in this case.